Is it possible to receive touching events when subview is outside of superview without using hitTest methods?
I have a video player view controller (I'm gonna call it PlayerVC) that consists of an AVPlayer and a custom timeline view. In one of my features I can add 2 PlayerVCs to a super view controller as their child view controllers.
It looks like this:

I have a feature where I can have 2 separate PlayerVCs and play both videos using a single timeline. What I do is this:
// In my Parent View Controller
func addSecondPlayer() {
    let playerVC = PlayerVC()
    addChild(playerVC)
    playerVC.didMove(toParent: self)

    // Setting some constraints below...
}

// Stretching my timeline
func stretchTimelineConstraint(_ stretch: Bool) {
        guard let parent else { return }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([timelineContainerViewLeadingConstraint])
        
        if stretch {
            timelineContainerViewLeadingConstraint = timelineContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.leadingAnchor)
        } else {
            timelineContainerViewLeadingConstraint = timelineContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([timelineContainerViewLeadingConstraint])
    }

So it will look pretty much like this:

Here I used the timeline of the right PlayerVC so I set the leading constraint to match the Parent View Controller to stretch the timeline to the whole width of the Parent View Controller. But now I can't scroll the timeline outside the it's PlayerVC's bounds (which is one on the right). Is there anyway to solve this? FYI, I'm using this library for the timeline view.
